# Programatically open a excel document using javascript office api

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, javascript-api-for-office

How to programatically open a document using javascript office api ?

Is there a way to insert a document using javascript office api Or to get access to the document xml ? Something like this

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) { 
    var application = ctx.workbook.application;
    application.load('newXmlWorkbook', worbookInXmlFormat);
    return ctx.sync().then(function() {
        console.log(application.calculationMode);
    });
}).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
});
```

Comment: this is for browser? you can't.
Or node.js?

Comment: No, I have an Excel add-in built with javascript office api and I have a cloud storage with documents, I want when I click the document from my add-in, to load the document in Excel

Comment: In a similar scenario, we open documents within a new instance of Word with this JS code `window.open('ms-word:ofv|u|' + filename);` For Excel, `window.open('ms-excel:ofv|u|' + filename);`.

Answer (score 3):

In Word an add-in can insert an entire document with the [Document.insertFileFromBase64()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt598674.aspx#insertfilefrombase64base64file_string_insertlocation_insertlocation) method.

In Excel this API isn't available. As an alternative, you can enable a download of the file instead of a replacement: for example, you can add an HTML link to the file and let the user download it or you can trigger the download yourself in JavaScript.

-Michael (PM for Office add-ins)

Comment: Hi, Michael! Could you take a look at the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063158/overlay-item-for-all-slides-in-powerpoint

Comment: Is Document.insertFileFromBase64() still valid?

Comment: @Amitabh looks like the method moved to `Body` class: https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/body