# Excel Addin - How to trigger document download in desktop version

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I am developing an Excel add-in using Office JS in which a user can decide to open a document from a remote server API. In that case I need to receive a file from the server API and open it in Excel.

I already found this answer: [Programatically open a excel document using javascript office api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35868577/programatically-open-a-excel-document-using-javascript-office-api/35901118#35901118)

So I see that the API does not allow this, and the answer suggests triggering the download using JS.

So I added an `iframe` to the addin page:

```
<iframe id="download" width="1" height="1" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

And to trigger the document download I am doing:

```
document.getElementById("download").src = downloadURL;
```

That works perfectly when trying online (Office 365).

But it is not downloading the document using the desktop version.

How can I make the solution word in desktop Excel application?

Comment: I would like to help but I am a little unclear what the problem is; more information would be helpful.  Your app is to download a document from an API and the API "allows" Office 365 to download it but the API does not "allow" Excel [..insertVersion#please..] to download it?  Is the API giving an error specific to Excel?  More than that I'd like to know more about the file.  Is this a static file or you do need to trigger dynamic generation?  Are you able to share the URL for testing?  Depending on the answer I may have a workable/workaround solution.  ...bah, I will start a "potential answer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no API in Excel to allow you to create/open document programmatically.  Word *does* have it, and there is a suggestion -- currently under investigation-- for doing the same for Excel as well (https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/15034512-ability-to-open-replace-workbook-with-excel-js-api).  But, there is not ETA that we can share yet.

That being said, you can absolutely pop up a "save as" dialog.  In fact, if you've seen [Script Lab](https://aka.ms/scriptlab), our "Export for publishing" does just that.

[image: "Export for publishing" menu option]

For Script Lab, we use the [FileSaver NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver).  If you want to see the bit of Script Lab code that makes use of it, see [this file](https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab/blob/05f5a7c553345fecb5735de2611cc79039c625e7/src/client/app/effects/github.ts), searching the area around `FileSaver.saveAs`.  Note, however, that the save-as dialog does not seem to work correctly on Mac or iOS, so at the moment we limited this functionality to just Desktop and Office Online (you can see a platform check towards the beginning of that method).

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks!!! one caveat: FileSaver does not seem to work for me in Win7 + IE11, so I had to use a different method to save the Blob (msSaveBlob)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you're trying to do, I have a potential solution.

One way to download a file from a URL with minimal coding is via the command-line with the Background Intelligent Transfer Service ([BITSAdmin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362812(v=vs.85).aspx)) Tool included with Windows.

This example downloads a cooking chart, in the background, to the location (and filename) you specify:

```
Sub testDownloadFileFromCMD()
    Const source_downloadURL = "http://instantpot.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Cooking-Time-Tables-1.pdf"
    Const dest_PathFilename = "C:\downloadedPDFFile.pdf"
    Shell ("bitsadmin /transfer wcb /priority high " & source_downloadURL & " " & dest_PathFilename)
End Sub
```

It shows the progress window but that can be optionally hidden.

Does your URL work with BITS?

If this *doesn't* work then there are many other ways to download a file but I'll definitely need more information.  I'm not sure what you mean by "the API *allows* Outlook365 but doesn't *allow* Excel to download the file".  Is the API giving an error?   More about this file... Is it Text/Binary?  What kind of file.  Is it large enough that size could be a problem?   Are you able to download the file in other ways, like directly with a browser?

I hope this helps and if not I'll have more to say!  :-)